# Words generating in Python

Tags: python

Let's consider we have an alphabet `{'0','1'}` and want to create a list of all words of length n, so they don't contain two zeros in a row. My idea of this implementation goes around:

```
def words(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ['']
    return [a+b for b in words(n-1) for a in ['0','1'] if a != '0' or b != '0']
```

The output of *words(3)* is the following:

```
['010', '110', '001', '101', '011', '111']
                 ^is the wrong one
```

Can you see my mistake or where my idea of generator goes wrong?

Comment: in the recursive call of `n=2` you end up with `['01', '11']`. Now for both it holds that `b != '0'` so you will concatenate both `0` and `1` to the left (as `a`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that once `b` grows to more than one character, it can never evaluate as equal to `'0'`. As you actually ask about the first letter of `b`, python has a [string method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) ready for you:

```
def words(n):                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if n == 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        return ['']                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return [a+b for b in words(n-1) for a in ['0','1'] if a != '0' or not b.startswith('0')]
```

The interface is kept, so you can e.g.:

```
words(3)  # ['010', '110', '101', '011', '111']
```